# Select records with certain value but exclude if it has another one

Tags: sql

So I have this table

```
Product_ID Client_ID
1          2
1          3
2          2
3          2
```

Basically I need to select the `product_ID`'s that's exclusive to `client_id = 2`. In my case it should return only the 2 and 3 `product_ID` as the one with `id = 1` is not exclusive and has multiple clients setup.

Comment: `select a.Product_ID
from ClientsProducts a
where a.Client_ID = '2' and not exists 
(SELECT *
                              FROM clients b 
                              WHERE a.Client_ID= b.CID AND a.Client_ID<> '2')`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it.

First, let's create your table.

```
create table SomeTable
(
    Product_ID int,
    Client_ID int
)
Go

insert into SomeTable values(1, 2)
insert into SomeTable values(1, 3)
insert into SomeTable values(2, 2)
insert into SomeTable values(3, 2)
```

The following script will return a list of all `Product_ID` values which have *just one* `Client_ID` value:

```
SELECT Product_ID
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Product_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

And you make this a sub-clause to get the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT st.Product_ID
FROM SomeTable st,
(
    SELECT Product_ID
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY Product_ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) tmp (Product_ID)
WHERE tmp.Product_ID = st.Product_ID
and st.Client_ID = 2
```

This will give you the row results (2 and 3) that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select product_id from ClientsProducts where client_id in (
Select client_ID from 
(select client_ID,count(product_id) from ClientsProducts
group by client_ID
having count(product_id)=1) a )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT Product_ID
FROM ClientsProducts
GROUP BY Product_ID
HAVING COUNT(Product_ID) = 1
```

OUTPUT

```
Product_ID
2
3
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/841ba7/14/0